# How to use an up-value assignment when all symbols are "too deep"?

Tags: assignment, upvalues

I would like to make an up-value assignment such as

```
a/:Conjugate[a[x]]a[x]+Conjugate[b[x]]b[x] = 1
```

or

```
b/:Conjugate[a[x]]a[x]+Conjugate[b[x]]b[x] = 1
```

or

```
x/:Conjugate[a[x]]a[x]+Conjugate[b[x]]b[x] = 1
```

Unfortunately, in all cases Mathematica complains that the symbol is too deep to attach this up-value assignment to it. Is there a way to trick Mathematica to use this up-value, or realize it by some other means?

Comment: With respect to tricking Mathematica to use up-values, the answer is ***no***. As for "realize it by some other means", since you don't give any context for what you expect Mathematica to do with `Conjugate[a[x]] a[x] + Conjugate[b[x]] b[x] = 1`, that is unanswerable.

Comment: @m_goldberg I believe an upvalue like `x/:head[x]=y` will substitute `head[x]->y` everywhere, while attaching the information about the substitution to `x` instead of `head`. In the case described in my question I would expect Mathematica to behave analogously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer.

If one allows for `f = Plus`, `g = Times` and `h = Conjugate` then the *rhs* of the assignments in the question can be written as `f[g[a[x], h[a[x]]], g[b[x], h[b[x]]]]`.

Now, forgetting for a moment the attempted assignments and focusing only on the derived expression ie `f[g[a[x], h[a[x]]], g[b[x], h[b[x]]]]`, it is evident that one *cannot* assign `UpValues` to symbols `a, b, x` because they appear too deep in the expression.

If the intended use of the code is to make algebraic manipulations of expressions involving symbols `a, b` and their `Conjugate`'s then perhaps doing something like the following might be helpful:

1. Define `UpValues` for symbols `a, b` relating their use wrt to `Times`:

   ```
   a /: a[x_] Conjugate[a[x_]] := timesConjugate[a[x]]
   b /: b[x_] Conjugate[b[x_]] := timesConjugate[b[x]]
   ```

   Please note that if the code intends to tackle more symbols like `a, b` eg like `c` then the list above should be extended in order to cover the use of those symbols, in a similar manner.
2. Define an `UpValue` for the auxiliary symbol `timeConjugate` wrt to `Plus`, when the arguments are `a, b`:

   ```
   timesConjugate /: timesConjugate[b[x_]] + timesConjugate[a[x_]] = 1
   ```

   Please note that if more symbols like `a, b` are used, then respective definitions of `timeConjugate` will have to be added to the list above in order to account for their use.

Now, hopefully after making the above definitions, expressions that involve `a, b` in the context of the expressions in the question, should evaluate to unity, as desired.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I think this tricks Mathematica into doing what I want alright! :)